# SSRS auto refresh on the hour

Tags: reporting-services

I want my report to be updated on the hour, e.g. 7:00, 8:00, 9:00. It can be achieved by setting the AutoRefresh property to 3600.

However, I have to open the report at the exact time (07:00 00:00) so it can be updated after 3600 seconds. If you open the report at 07:00 00:01, the next update time will be 08:00 00:02, and then 09:00 00:03. As a result, you have to refresh the report manually to make the update time correct.

Is there any way to make the report updated on the hour?

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS 2008 R2, you can set AutoRefresh by using an expression like this:

```
datediff("s", datetime.Now, dateadd("h", datediff("h", datetime.MinValue, datetime.Now) + 1, datetime.MinValue))
```

For update every half hour, try this:

```
datediff("s", datetime.Now, dateadd("n", floor(datediff("n", datetime.MinValue, datetime.Now)/30)*30+30, datetime.MinValue))
```